# How can I create In-line (form-horizontal) bootstrap forms using angularjs and formly?

Tags: angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, angular-formly

I would like to move my bootstrap forms from static HTML/Angularjs to Formly and AngularjS.  Here is how I currently create forms:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form role="form" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="qgOrder" class="col-md-3 control-label">Group Order</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input  id="qgOrder"
                        name="qgOrder"
                        ng-model="qG.qgOrder"
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control"
                        />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Additional <divs> repeated for additional input fields --!>
    </form>
</div>
```

This allows for the alignment of both the labels and the input form using class attributes from bootstrap `col-md-3` on the label and `col-md-xx` in the input form as required.

How can this be done with `angular-formly`?  I can create a simple in-line form by adding `className: "form-inline"`:

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <form >
        <formly-form model="vm.user" fields="vm.form"></formly-form>
    </form>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
vm.form = [{
    key: 'UserName',
    type: 'input',
    className: 'form-inline',
    templateOptions: { label: 'User' }
}];
```

but I can't figure out the secret sauce to fix the formatting.  A simple way, I would think, would to add class types to both the input and form elements, but how?  I would like to stay away from custom templates if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this still helpful.

I found a documented example on the formly site: 
http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/bootstrap-horizontal

For it to work its important (or it was for me) to notice that only the `type: 'horizontalInput'`  will not make the magic. it is required to configure the `formlyConfigProvider` within the app config, as documented. For me it was:

```
angular.module('appName', [
  ...
  'formly',
  'formlyBootstrap',
  ...
]).config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, formlyConfigProvider) {
    //.. other configuration... 
    // set templates here
    formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'horizontalBootstrapLabel',
      template: [
        '<label for="{{::id}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">',
        '{{to.label}} {{to.required ? "*" : ""}}',
        '</label>',
        '<div class="col-sm-8">',
        '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(' ')
    });

    formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'horizontalBootstrapCheckbox',
      template: [
        '<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">',
        '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(' ')
    });

    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
      name: 'horizontalInput',
      extends: 'input',
      wrapper: ['horizontalBootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError']
    });

    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
      name: 'horizontalCheckbox',
      extends: 'checkbox',
      wrapper: ['horizontalBootstrapCheckbox', 'bootstrapHasError']
    });
    //...
  });
```